# Write a word or special character in the selected areas automatically

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have high number of JPG files and now I want to write "#" in multiple selected areas by photoshop action.
for example in following I selected 4 area and I can record this by action:

[image]

[image]

after selection I want to write "#" in all selected areas automatically like following:

[image]

Note that in some images maybe photoshop selected more than 4 areas like following:

[image]

How can I do this by photoshop action? are there any script to do this?
Note that I don't want to split selected areas to multiple layers because I want to edit high number of images and it take long time.

3 Sample image as Gif file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tV8iOlEgq5ZZVQnfSIwKcAV-4rSGCl-F/view?usp=drive_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Op9oeIrp4hJiTglGl1FHWJZZrONBh6aH/view?usp=drive_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_vhKHPp6jBS9LBfkIrftWjY3Z8kDEN7A/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the only way you can do something like that with an **Action** is if the distance is the same between the lines you'd

- have your `#` layer ready;
- run `Free Transform` while holding `Alt` key to duplicate while transforming;
- place the duplicate where you want;
- in the Action you'd have `Repeat Transform with Copy` (`Edit > Transform > Repeat Transform` while holding `Alt`);
- and then you'd play your Action that repeats transform and duplicates a layer N-times manually;

A **Script** however would be able to do the same in one go. Here's the algorithm:

- first transform the selection into a Path — you'll get a Subpath object for each selection "island";
- iterate through the Subpaths and get points coordinates to calculate where to put your `#` layers;
- for each coordinate duplicate and place your layer;